# Call method from component A in to component B

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem. I have one method in component A, and I want to call this method in component B from constructor. Example:

```
 export class A {
     methodA() {
      do something;
      }

    }



export class B {
    constructor(private a:A){}
         methodB() {
          this.a.methodA();
          }

        }
```

And I have this problem :`Can't resolve all parameters for CategoryComponent`

Comment: `https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb` this link is help you how to communicate with component

Comment: Parent access to child ? Use `ViewChild`. Child access to parent ? Use `Output`.

Answer (score 0):

[Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction) best practice in angular depends on the relation between the 2 components.

Make thing short:

1. Parent and Child relation: we'll communicate the 2 of them by [@Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) and @Output variables.
2. Component that doesn't know each other: will have an injected [service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) to communicate by.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add your `A` component to your `B` component's provider, so your `class B` should look like this

```
import {A} from 'path/to/A.component';
// other imports

@Component({
  selector: 'b-component',
  templateUrl: './b.component.html',
  providers: [A] // this is what you are missing
})
export class B implements OnInit {

    constructor(private a: A) {
    }

    // move function out of constructor
    ngOnInit() {
        this.methodB();
    }

    methodB() {
        this.a.methodA();
    }
}
```

Also, it is not good practice to add any logic to the constructor. You really should use it in `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: This is very bad, component is **not** a provider. communication between components are made by 1. input/output if it is a child parent relation. 2. by services  if it isn't.

Comment: I don't know the relationship is between component A and B. are they parent/child? is is service/component? is it common functions/single page? is it a class that could be a super? I don't know, it seems like a new user that is calling everything a component. I added a solution that would work for the user that provided minimal information on the use case

Comment: I see your point, but in that case the shared service is the right approach and a component shouldn't be provided to another one, it should only hold his own logic, it doesn't make sense that another component would need to use one of it's functions

Comment: If there is some shared logic/function that both component use, it should be placed in a shared service